# YADR and RVM problems in iTerm2

Tags: ruby, terminal, rvm, zsh, iterm2

I recently installed the YADR package onto iTerm2. However, after the install I get an RVM prompt `[ruby2.1.2 ...]` on the right side of every line I type.

Is there any way to get rid of this?

[image]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hbix1kufao0supe/Screen%20Shot%202014-10-01%20at%2012.50.33%20PM.png?dl=0

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to modify any code, you can do it with yadr hooks instead:

In ~/.zsh.after/myPrompt.zsh add the line:

```
RPROMPT=''
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. There's a folder called prezto and inside you have a bunch of themes. The default theme is the skwp theme, so just go in there and change a few lines of code.

Comment: For the curious ones: https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles/blob/master/zsh/prezto-themes/prompt_skwp_setup, this is the file where one can see RPROMPT being set.